# White Background issue around "Sign in with Google" Button and "One Tap" Popup

Tags: angular, npm, google-signin, google-api-js-client, angular-social-login

I am using the new google sign in button and one tap login in angular. Currently, I am using a library [@abacritt/angularx-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login/). I tried directly using the `/gsi/client` script and this one also gave the same result only. Atatching image for reference.

[image: White Background]

I tried disabling all styles on my application. but nothing changed. When I directly inspect the button/popup and apply some color to body of the dynamically generated iframe, the colors are changing. no other colors are affected.

below is my html setup according to library docs.

```
<asl-google-signin-button GoogleSigninButtonDirective type='standard' size="large" width="320"
    theme="filled_blue">
</asl-google-signin-button>
```

below is app module.

```
{
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {        
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              'clientId_here',
            ),            
          }
        ],
        onError: (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        },
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    }
```

The issue seems that not related to this specific package because I tried without using any package and gave same results.

Comment: Could you inspect the HTML within the chrome developer tools and check whether there's a background style being applied? That would be a great way to both debug these type of issues in the future and to provide more insight to the person attempting to answer.

Comment: Yes @saguirrews. I checked all elements using inspect. It is a dynamically generated iframe and there is no background color applied anywhere for all elements. but somehow the body tag is getting a white background.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this happen when the page was in dark theme, with `color-scheme: dark` set in CSS or with a meta tag.

Putting `color-scheme: light` on the button/one-tap popup container or on the iframe itself solved it.

Comment: To be more specific: <div id="oneTap" data-itp_support="true" style={{ colorScheme: 'light'}} />